# chrome.browsingData.removeCache() vs Clear browsing data: Empty the cache

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What does the `"Empty the cache"` function of Chrome's `"Clear browsing data"` dialog use?

It clears the cache more thoroughly compared to

```
chrome.browsingData.removeCache({ "since": 0, "originTypes": {"unprotectedWeb": true, "protectedWeb": true, "extension": true}})
```

The Chrome in-built made the `index, data_0, data_1, data_2` and `data_3` files smaller plus deleted the `f_00000` files.

But `chrome.browsingData.removeCache()` doesn't do anything to those 5 files and only deletes the `f_00000` files.

Is there any way to replicate the method used Chrome's `"Clear browsing data"` dialog?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for DataTypeSet says that "Missing data types are interpreted as false." You haven't listed any data types whatsoever, so you'd expect the call to clear nothing at all. You do have a syntax error in the method call (an extra comma in `"since": 0, , "originTypes"...`), so it's possible that in the code that inspired this question, you've correctly listed every data type. But as you've stated the question, it shouldn't clear anything.

Comment: That extra comma is actually a typo on my part, in the code the syntax is right and theres no errors in the console.

Regarding the DataTypeSet according to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData.html#method-removeCache), the removeCache() method doesn't need to take in a DataTypeSet object.
It only require RemovalOptions and an optional callback function.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I was reading the documentation for chrome.browsingData.remove(). Are you finding that the method is leaving actual browsing data around? Or are you just concerned about the extra files in the directory? It's likely Chrome is not garbage-collecting index data that improves cache access. You might want to [file a bug](http://crbug.com/) if you consider it to be buggy behavior.

Comment: I just want to confirm if what I posted is the intended behavior of the removeCache() method. That is it designed to be inferior to the built-in Chrome option.

Maybe I'll try filing a bug.

Comment: I filed a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=249295) the discussion turn into something deep that I don't understand but its been assigned and they are looking into it I think.